# can't find boost c++ using configure.ac

Tags: c++, r, boost, package, autoconf

I wrote a configure.ac to find the path of boost c++ inlclude, but it could not find anything. If I specify the path, it can compile. Could anyone help me please?
Here is my configure.ac

```
AC_PREREQ([2.67])
AC_INIT(pkg, 1.1.01)
AC_PROG_CXX

AC_ARG_WITH(
[boost],
[AS_HELP_STRING(
    [--with-boost=DIR],
    [path to look for Boost])
],
[boostpath=$withval],
   [boostpath=]
)

if test -n "$boostpath"; then
boostinc="-I$boostpath/include"
fi

CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS ${boostinc}"

AC_SUBST([CXXFLAGS])

AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makevars])
AC_OUTPUT
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: -I arguments belong in CPPFLAGS, not CXXFLAGS

Comment: Where do you invoke AC_CHECK_HEADERS?  Standard usage is for you to invoke AC_CHECK_HEADERS in configure.ac and, if the headers are installed in a non-standard location, have the user specify the location in CPPFLAGS: ./configure CPPFLAGS=-I/p/a/t/h.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`AX_BOOST_BASE`](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_boost_base.html) from the [autoconf-archive](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive).

If you're trying to `AC_CHECK_HEADERS` to verify the existence of boost headers, remember that you need to `AC_LANG_PUSH([C++])` first, or you'll get "header present but cannot be compiled" errors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am trying to use AX_BOOST_BASE([1.45]), but it gives me error message:

Comment: Then post the error message as an edit to your original question. I'm not psychic.

Comment: sorry, i use ./configure to check if it can run, and the error messages are:                                              ./configure: line 2666: syntax error near unexpected token '1.45'     ./configure: line 2666" 'AX_BOOST_BASE(1.45>'

Comment: You need to download the `.m4` file from the autoconf-archive and put it somewhere `aclocal` will see it (such as `./m4/ax_boost_base.m4`). Call `AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])` in configure.ac and `ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4` in Makefile.am (if you use automake), then run autoreconf. Alternatively, install the autoconf-archive through your package manager.